# How to target li:before and link when hover over link?

Tags: html, css

I have an `ol` with custom numbering using `:before`.

Each `li` contains an `a`.

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/ggjpJP)

**HTML**

```
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
</ol>
```

When a user hovers over the link I want both the link and the custom number to change colour.

**Problem:**

Because the `:before` belongs to the parent (the `li`), hover events on the link can't target it.

**Attempted solution:**

I created a hover effect on the `li` instead. But this allows a hover that is *outside* of the link to cause a change in colour (i.e. not directly over it).

Changing the `li` to `display: inline-block` messes up the formatting.

Is there a simple way to change the colour of **both** the link and the pseudoelement when the **link** is hovered over?

The HTML can be easily amended if necessary.

**Snippet**

```css
body {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
pre {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 4px;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol li {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.inline li{
  display: inline-block;
}

ol li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(item) " ";
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-left: -2em;
  width: 2em;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
  color: red;
}

li:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><pre>display: block</pre> - causes hover effect outside of link </p>
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
</ol>
<hr />
<p><pre>display: inline-block</pre> - organises list in a row
<ol class="inline">
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Is it necessary that the number you are adding not be a part of the link? If not, you could simply move the :before from the li tag to the a.

Comment: @KristenVogler No the number does not need to be part of the link. That's a valid point, but I'm not sure how it would work semantically. Would the numbers increment in the same way? I might have to add different :before to each anchor...

Comment: I agree.  Placing the number on the anchor is the logical conclusion.  Even if you get the hover effect to change the number color using the `li`, it runs the risk of sending the wrong message in the user experience.  I assume the hover is an indicator of interactivity.  If you hover over the number and it changes color, but does nothing when clicked that creates an inconsistent user experience.

Comment: I just changed your css selector from ol li:before to a:before, and then just used a:hover{ color:red} instead of any reference to li:hover. It incremented the same way for me. Give it a shot, hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: @KristenVogler - You are right. I didn't expect the pseudoselector to increment in the same way. Thanks, this is the the better solution. If you want to post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Good points, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving the :before from your "ol li" css to your "a" selector.
From:

```
ol li:before {
display: inline-block;
content: counter(item) " ";
counter-increment: item;
margin-left: -2em;
width: 2em;
}
```

To:

```
a:before {
display: inline-block;
content: counter(item) " ";
counter-increment: item;
margin-left: -2em;
width: 2em;
}
```

Then instead of worrying about selecting a part of the li on a hover you can simply use a:hover and it will change both the number and the text of your link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little trick with `li` that has a `display: block`:

```
 width: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
```

Look at snippet:

```css
body {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
pre {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 4px;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol li {
  margin-left: 2em;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ol li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(item) " ";
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-left: -2em;
  width: 2em;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
  color: red;
}

li:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><pre>display: block</pre> - doesn't cause hover effect outside of link </p>
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sample text</a></li>
</ol>
```